# Callbacks from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have a subject/observer system in C++:

```
#include <vector>
class IObserver
{
public:
    virtual void valueChanged(float pos) = 0; 
};

class Subject
{
public:
    static Subject *instance();
    void subscribe(IObserver *observer);
private:
    static Subject*                    m_instance;
    std::vector<IObserver*>            m_observers;
};
```

I need to implement an observer in C# and subscribe to the subject.
How do I do this?

I could maybe use function pointers:

```
typedef void (*ValueChangedFunc)(float pos);
void SubscribeTovalueChanged(ValueChangedFunc func); // global but works on singleton
```

How would I convert a C# member function to a C++ function pointer and call the last function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# can't implement C++ interfaces, that needs to be done from C++.

You can either use C++/CLI to make a shim observer implementing the interface that also understands C# delegates, or you can use standard C++ to make a shim observer implementing the interface and calling a function pointer; C# delegates can be converted to function pointers.

A final way is for the C++ code to use a full-blown COM interface (described in IDL), which C# can implement, instead of a minimal C++ interface.

---

For your new code with function pointers:

First, specify the calling convention on the C++ side.

```
typedef void (__stdcall *ValueChangedFunc)(float pos);
void __stdcall SubscribeToValueChanged(ValueChangedFunc func); // global but works on singleton
```

Then declare a delegate matching the function-pointer typedef.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Stdcall)]
delegate void ValueChangedFunc(float);
```

And then declare the function that consumes it:

```
[DllImport(...)]
void SubscribeToValueChanged(ValueChangedFunc func);
```

Note that function pointers in use in native code are not visible to the garbage collector.  It is **your responsibility** to keep the delegate alive for as long as the function pointer is stored.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben! Regarding converting C# delegate to function pointer. How would I do this?

Comment: @Andy: [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at4fb09f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This would give me a IntPtr ptr. How can I convert this to void* and call a C function: void subscribe(void *p)?

Comment: @Andy: (1) Don't.  Just use `IntPtr` in the p/invoke declaration.  (2) `void*` is not a function pointer type.  The nifty thing about  `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` is that it doesn't require a singleton; the JIT compiler generates native code that contains a reference to your particular object, and forwards to an instance method on that object.  (3) Even better, write a delegate type in the p/invoke declaration.  p/invoke will call `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` for you.